# Create a Dictionary/Object from a JQuery Response

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

This JQuery `$$('tbody[class="MuiTableBody-root"]')[5].innerText` returns

```
"Subtotal   $0.00
Total   $0.00
Total Price/Unit    $0.00"
```

There is a new line character after the dollar amount, and there are additional spaces in the string.

How can I insert in/or create a dictionary to store the above response as shown below?

store = {
'Subtotal': $0.00,
'Total': $0.00,
'Total Price/Unit': $0.00"
}

DOM:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Subtotal</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total Price/Unit</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the regex on the response. Why is it only matching 2?[image]

Comment: Might be simpler to capture individual trimmed cells text to do this. What does a sample row html look like? See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I can use different selectors to acquire each row. Are you suggesting just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex applied with `matchAll()` to return an iterator of matches which you can map to an array of `[key, value]` pairs using `Array.from()` which can then be passed to `Object.fromEntries` to yield your final object.

```
const response = `Subtotal   $0.00
Total   $0.00
Total Price/Unit    $0.00`

const regex = /(.*?)(?=\$)(\$\d+.\d+)(?=[\r|\n]|$)/g;

// return iterator from matchAll() 
const matchIterator = response.matchAll(regex);

// pass the iterator to Array.from() and use built in map() 
// to return a [key, value] array with white space removed by trim()
const keyValueArr = Array.from(matchIterator, ([_, key, value]) => ([key.trim(), value.trim()]));

// pass the array to Object.fromEntries()
const finalObject = Object.fromEntries(keyValueArr);

// Or all in one call...
const 
  reg = /(.*?)(?=\$)(\$\d+.\d+)(?=[\r|\n]|$)/g,
  object = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(response.matchAll(reg), ([_, key, value]) => ([key.trim(), value.trim()])));
```

---

```js
const response = `Subtotal   $0.00
Total   $0.00
Total Price/Unit    $0.00`

const 
  reg = /(.*?)(?=\$)(\$\d+.\d+)(?=[\r|\n]|$)/g,
  object = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(response.matchAll(reg), ([_, key, value]) => ([key.trim(), value.trim()])));


console.log(object);
```

---

Or using DOM traversal

```js
const 
  rows = document.querySelectorAll('.MuiTableBody-root tr'),
  object = Object.fromEntries(
      [...rows].map(r => [...r.cells].map(c => c.innerText.trim()))
    );

console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Subtotal</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="MuiTableRow-root">
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">Total Price/Unit</td>
    <td class="MuiTableCell-root jss93 MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignRight">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach mapping multiple tbody elements to array of objects by iterating each row and cell for individual trimmed text values

```js
const data = $('tbody.MuiTableBody-root').map((i, tbod) => {
  return [...tbod.rows].reduce((a, row) => {
    const [k, v] = [...row.cells].map(cell => cell.textContent.trim())
    return (a[k] = v, a);   
  }, {})
}).get();

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
    <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td>$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Price/Unit</td>
      <td>$0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
    <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Price/Unit</td>
      <td>$1.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this

```
let res = `Subtotal   $0.00
Total   $0.00
Price/Unit    $0.00`;

let parts = res.split('\n').map(item => item.split(' ').filter( i=> i != ""));

let myObj = parts.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj[0]] = obj[1];
    return map;
}, {});
```

Comment: You need to account for keys that may have spaces in them – `Total Price/Unit` not `Price/Unit`